# Is there any way to play Left 4 Dead on a LAN?

Tags: left-4-dead

It seems the only option for playing Left 4 Dead with my friends is to have all computers online, even though I bought the 4 pack from Valve. Is there anyway to plan a LAN game on Left 4 Dead 1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible. If you use [srcds](http://srcds.com/) to set up a dedicated server and note the LAN IP of the computer hosting it, you can enable the developer console in-game (under Keyboard settings then advanced) press the <kbd>~</kbd> key (on foreign keyboards, it is usually whichever key is next to the <kbd>1</kbd> key) to open it and enter the command `connect <LAN IP of server>` into it. You'll then be dropped into the game. Make sure to edit the key of the server so that random people don't start joining. Consider setting it to LAN-only.

If you're using a non-QWERTY keyboard, sometimes binding the developer console may not work. If so, you can edit the launch options and add `--console`. Then, whenever you launch the game, you'll have console open.

Comment: All clients have to be connected to the internet throughout, though. Steam DRM still applies.

Comment: @Bora Nope. You can run Steam in offline mode, and play it on a LAN. I've done it before.

Comment: Ok, scratch the throughout part. You have to connect to Steam once to switch to offline, at least.

Comment: @Bora Also not true. If you reboot your computer without a working internet connection, Steam offers you the option to switch to offline, assuming you have logged in some time before that.

Comment: I was referring to the "some time before that" part, which might render the whole process inconvenient, just for the sake of getting around the DRM process.

Comment: @Bora In that sense you are correct. Most people have Steam set-up to auto-login, but I do realise that this is not the case for everyone. Sorry for the confusion.